# if blocks with static variables

Tags: java, android

I work with both objective-c and java. In the former I have access to preprocessing directives, so I can define printing statements for debugging that don't use cycles when undefined.

Since Java does not have the ability I was curious how the compiler handles something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public void printMessage(String message) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            //sysout
        } 
    } 
}
```

Will each call to printMessage diminish performance, or will the compiler recognize that DEBUG is always false and compensate for each call?
Is there a better way to handle this that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

**Such blocks are automatically optimized by the compiler. i.e., they do not stay inside the compiled code.**

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
            log("hello world");
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }

    private static void log(String message) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

}
```

If you run the above code, It will run in **0 ms**.

If you open the compiled class file (I opened it form IntelliJ IDEA), you can see that the method `log` is empty as below:

```
private static void log(String message) {
}
```

But on the other hand, if you make the variable `DEBUG` **not final**, the body of the `log` function stays in the compiled code. And it will take around **15 ms** to run the code.